# Unable to resolve **Object is possibly 'undefined'**

Tags: typescript

When I call this method in my test and I pass in the argument, I am getting the above error **Object is possibly 'undefined'**. Please help, I am new to typescript. I have attached a screenshot below.

```
async monthlyReviewTitleText(titleText: string) {

    const monthlyReviewTitleText = await
 
    driver.$$(generateCssClassSelector('monthly-review-title-text'));
    
    for (let i = 0; i < monthlyReviewTitleText.length; i++) {

        const monthlyReviewTitle = monthlyReviewTitleText[i];

        if (await monthlyReviewTitle.getText() === titleText) {

            return await monthlyReviewTitle.getText();
        }
     }
  }
```

Output:
This where I am getting the error

```
expect( await (await HightlightsTab.monthlyReviewTitleText('Vehicles in Recon')).isDisplayed());
```

Comment: on which line does the error occur ? Is this one: `const monthlyReviewTitleText = await
 driver.$$(...)` ?

Comment: No it occurs in the test 

expect(await (await HightlightsTab.monthlyReviewTitleText('Vehicles in Recon')).isDisplayed());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS will try its best to guest your function signature

```
async monthlyReviewTitleText(titleText: string) {
  const monthlyReviewTitleText = await driver.$$(generateCssClassSelector('monthly-review-title-text'));

  for (let i = 0; i < monthlyReviewTitleText.length; i++) {
    const monthlyReviewTitle = monthlyReviewTitleText[i];

    if ((await monthlyReviewTitle.getText()) === titleText) {
      return await monthlyReviewTitle.getText(); <- return here if condition satisfy
    }
  }
  // if end of loop but no element found
  // return undefined implicitly
}
```

Based on your code, TS know there are 2 code path possible:

1. If condition satisfy then return `await monthlyReviewTitle.getText();`
2. If end of loop but no element found, then `undefined` is returned (implicitly)

Hence when you use function `monthlyReviewTitleText`:

```
await HightlightsTab.monthlyReviewTitleText('Vehicles in Recon');
```

It might return undefined here, that why TS will warning you since if you chain `undefined.something` an error will occur at runtime

To fix that, you can use `?` safe navigation operator

```
expect( await HightlightsTab.monthlyReviewTitleText('Vehicles in Recon')?.isDisplayed());
```

Comment: Thank you. I applied that and it works @somallg